# How can I show an absolutely positioned div inside a fixed positioned div?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
 <div id="main">
        <div class="dummy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis enim molestias illo id voluptas tempora minima sunt fugiat voluptatibus voluptatem dolores omnis iste. Fuga facilis adipisci similique explicabo sunt alias! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam omnis esse saepe eveniet modi harum quae laborum eaque vero nesciunt consequuntur placeat nisi velit commodi minima itaque voluptatem necessitatibus quasi.</div>
        <div id="inner">I want this div to slide left on some action</div>
        <div class="dummy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis enim molestias illo id voluptas tempora minima sunt fugiat voluptatibus voluptatem dolores omnis iste. Fuga facilis adipisci similique explicabo sunt alias! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam omnis esse saepe eveniet modi harum quae laborum eaque vero nesciunt consequuntur placeat nisi velit commodi minima itaque voluptatem necessitatibus quasi.</div>
    </div>
```

Please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N73yy/5) to view the full code with associated CSS.

I want the black inner `div` container to be visible even outside the main `div` container, but also want to give `overflow:auto` to the main `div` so that if content in the red `div` increases, a scroll bar should come. These things are not working together. 
Please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/N73yy/2/)?

I added the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="preventOverflow">
```

CSS:

```
 #preventOverflow
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

It is not possible to merge two scroll bars of seperate blocks with a div in between them. I would recommend changing the layout.

Comment: hi Christopher your solution is perfect for my question asked above...but i actually want the answer for the edited question..

Comment: Hi, I consider this as impossible. There is no CSS way of doing this. I also had this problem once. Change the layout, if you can. There has to be a way around it.

Comment: impossible...this word sucks, but i think you are right.I need to change the layout.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry for that. Hope your question is answered.

Answer (score -1):

do you mean this...

```
 #inner {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   left: 59px;
   position: inherit;
   top: 5px;
   width: 80px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/xRasu/

Comment: User wants the div to be flowing left from the inner div and still be visible `I want the black div.inner container to be visible even outside the div`. You have adjusted the div to fit in the outer div.